# MSVC Heap Reserve/Commit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, heap-memory

I wrote a program that requires ~1GB of RAM zeroed at startup, and this is taking more time than the rest of the program combined from a cold start. (it's a simple program, subsequent runs take almost no time at all to allocate).  When watched via task manager, it starts with almost no RAM, and then grows about 2MB/sec until it reaches the 1GB it needs.  I found options "Heap Reserve Size" and "Heap Commit Size", and set them to 1000000000 each, but when I watched the program via task manager, the program appears to start at 1GB, and then grow at that 2MB/sec until I get a bad_alloc.  The line in question is:
`std::vector<std::vector<char> > data(512, std::vector<byte>(2097252, 0));`
Can someone clearly explain what these options are for, and if there is a way to use them to speed my allocations?  I have read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90ybzkh(v=vs.80).aspx, but it doesn't explain the behavior I observed.

Comment: Wrong heap, that's the process heap, not the CRT heap.  Sounds like your pagefile has trouble growing, common on old XP machines.  Check out the SysInternals' PageDefrag utility.

Comment: I can't answer my own question for seven more hours, but I realized it's probably because the first run has to page stuff out of RAM to the hard drive, whereas the subsequent run has all that unused RAM left behind after the first run.  The allocation/zeroing has nothing to do with it.  Sorry all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized it's probably because the first run has to page stuff out of RAM to the hard drive, whereas the subsequent run has all that unused RAM left behind after the first run. The allocation/zeroing has nothing to do with it. Sorry all.

Answer (score 3):

Your memory allocation is not causing your speed issues. Your speed issues are being caused by copying ~2MB of zeros 512 times. Changing those properties isn't going to help you.

I would investigate efficient ways of zeroing out memory, rather than relying on `std::vector` to do it for you. Or, at the very least, don't pass a std::vector of 2MB of data as an argument to the constructor. Let the default constructor create 512 empty vectors, then resize each of them to 2MB. At least that won't be a memory copy; just a bunch of memory writes.

Comment: I will look into more efficent ways to zero memory as you say, but since the operation is nearly instant on subsequent runs, it seems dubious to me that this is the problem.  I'll try to remember to time it when I get home.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the allocation might not be the choke-point.  You got me on the right track to figuring it out.